# .NET Core missing header from HttpClient DefaultRequestHeaders

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried to call an API which requires to include some information in the header. The parameter (dictionary) is a constant, hence there are always values available in the dictionary. However, the API will be returning "missing header". It could be missing on the first call, but successful on the second call. It has 14 headers in total. And the headers that are able to reach the API aren't consistent. Sometimes only 5, sometimes only 3, and sometimes all.

```
public bool CheckBackEndConnection(Dictionary<string, string> backendConfig, out string errorMessage)
{
        var result = false;
        errorMessage = string.Empty;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            backendConfig.AsParallel().ForAll(record => { client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(record.Key, record.Value); });

            var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(backendConfig[nameof(Dev_BackendConfig.INTEGRATIONURL)] + "ConnectToBackEnd")).Result;
            result = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            if (!result)
            {
                errorMessage = "API CheckBackEndConnection " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe `DefaultRequestHeaders` is not thread safe. So based on info, that set of headers are always different, I would say the problem part is `AsParallel().ForAll(...)`. Please try add headers in same thread.

Comment: What's the point of `backendConfig.AsParallel().ForAll`? You're only adding a dozen headers at most, which means the parallelization overhead is larger than adding the headers.

Comment: There are other serious problems too. HttpClient shouldn't be disposed. It's thread-safe and *meant* to be reused. IJust create it once, add the default headers and use `await _client.GetAsync`. *Don't* use `.Result`, make the method itself asynchronous.

Comment: Also need to dispose `response` with `using`. Why would you need to parallelize adding a few headers?